# Moving an element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, inventory

I've searched around the net but can't seem to find quite the answer to my problem. Currently I'm organizing items of an inventory into an array, using the index of the array to generate positions for the GUI whenever the player opens that screen. However when the player moves the item I set the item at the old index in the array to null, which I quickly learned sets the slot item to null as well.

Essentially I just need to figure out how to remove the object from the old position and replace it at a new one. Is this possible?

I've considered switching over the inventory to an ArrayList but it would be nice if I didn't have to as it's structured around the use of an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this why God invented linked lists?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was Jesus that invented linked lists.

Comment: Accept as best answer if it helped!!

Comment: It made me wait a few minutes since you answered so quick ;)